# The mappedBy restriction of bidirectional Many-to-one relationship

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-one

I've searched for the reason behind the absence of `mappedBy` attribute of `ManyToOne` annotation, but I have not found the answer so far.

**I'm not interested in workarounds now (I found some)**, but the reason of the restriction. It could probably use the join table of the `OneToMany` side. So my question is: when we have a `OneToMany` relationship, where the "one" side is the owner, why is it impossible to have as a bidirectional relationship using `mappedBy`?

Comment: Workaround? The "mappedBy" simply makes the relation bidirectional and defines the owner side. In a 1-N relation the only side that can manage the relation is the collection side, hence it is on one side only, and you specify it on the `@OneToMany`!

Comment: Imagine a task where teachers can have multiple students, but students have only one teacher. The teachers have a unidirectional `OneToMany` relationship with the students. In the database a new table is generated: teacher_student.

Later, if I would like to expand this in order to reach the teacher from the student side, I cannot use `@ManyToOne(mappedBy="students")` explicitly. If I could do this then I would have only a little change in student class: creating a new attribute with this annotation. The database would not change at all. But for some reason, it is not allowed. Why?

Comment: You put `@ManyToOne` on the Student, and add `mappedBy` to the Teacher! so it becomes a 1-N BIDIRECTIONAL relation.

Comment: Your solution would cause database change: I have to drop the teacher_student table, and introduce a new column in student table. It works, it is a workaround in my opinion. My question is still open though.

Comment: Huh? You can model a 1-N BIDIRECTIONAL via JOIN TABLE or FK in the Student. You can model a 1-N UNIDIRECTIONAL via JOIN TABLE or FK in the Student. The user has full flexibility for all possibilities.

Comment: Yeah, I understand this, everything is clear. I just want to understand, why mappedBy can't be used in @ManyToOne as it could use the already generated join table for the inverse direction. Why do the restriction exist?